# Removing lubuntu-desktop removes only 15.4kb of files and auto-remove does not remove anything

Tags: lxde, lubuntu, delete

I installed Enlightenment and I want now to remove Lubuntu's LXDE environment, but when I ran the command to remove `lxde`, it said it was not installed, and when I tried to remove `lubuntu-desktop` it removed only 15.4kb of files and `auto-remove` did not remove anything at all.

```
Package 'lxde' is not installed, so not removed
```

---

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  lubuntu-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 15.4 kB disk space will be freed.
```

---

```
gabriel@gabriel:~$ sudo apt-get auto-remove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

How do I remove LXDE? Is it even safe to do so? Won't I lose the login screen or will it be replaced with pure terminal?

Answer (score 0):

lubuntu has a weird dependency on Firefox.  If you try to remove Firefox, it also removes lubuntu-desktop.

lubuntu-desktop appears to be part of the meta package.  I wouldn't try to remove lubuntu-desktop, unless you are making a server and don't need a gui.